# HTML code won’t update before launching

Tags: html

So I have been trying to make a test website but when I go to launch it, for some reason the code isn't the same code that I made. Here is what I mean...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Dosisod</title>

    <style>
        h.Main-Title{
            color:lightblue;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family:'Lucida Console';
        }
        p.Test{
            font-family:'Lucida Console';
            color:black;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h class="Main-Title">This Is A Test.</h>
    <p class="Test">This Is A Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I launch it, it doesn't look like that at all. And when i looked at the source code for the page, it looked like this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Dosisod</title>

    <style>
        .Main-Title{
            color:lightblue;
            font-size: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="Main-Title">This Is A Test.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Its missing a bunch of the code i had made, and disappears when i launch it. Maybe it is a build error?

Comment: try to clear the cache of your browser. If the problem still occur, clear the cache of your web server .

Comment: so just close all my tabs? I'm using Microsoft edge on windows 10 if that helps

Comment: thanks I just restarted my browser and it works XD I should've done that first I restarted VS but that didn't do anything.

Comment: glad to know it help. You can also clear the cache of browser using Ctrl + Shift + Delete. Or press the Ctrl + F5 to clear the cache of current page. Happy coding ;)

Comment: @Dosisod What does `h` tag do?